# .NET MVC SignalR unable to access sendImage

Tags: .net, signalr

I have my Chathub.cs with 2 func: SendText & SendImage. When form submitted then will call SendText and SendText works. But for SendImage, when file input change will call the SendImage but it doesn't go into it and didn't show any err msg on console window. What is the problem out here?

Javascript(Call SendText & SendImage):

```
$("#file-input").change(e => {
                let f = e.target.files[0];
                console.log(f);
                proxy.server.sendImage(name, f, photo);
            });
            $("form").submit(e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let text = $("#text").val().trim();
                if (text) {
                    proxy.server.sendText(name, text, photo);
                }
                $("#text").val("").focus();
            });
```

Chathub:

```
public void SendText(string name, string text, string photo)
    {
        var m = new ForumMessage
        {
            Id = NextForumId(),
            Message = text,
            PhotoURL = null,
            MemberEmail = name,
            MemberPhoto = photo
        };
        db.ForumMessages.Add(m);
        db.SaveChanges();

        Clients.Caller.ReceiveText(name, text, photo, "sender");
        Clients.Others.ReceiveText(name, text, photo, "caller");
    }

    

    public void SendImage(string name, HttpPostedFileBase url, string photo)
    {
        var m = new ForumMessage
        {
            Id = NextForumId(),
            Message = null,
            PhotoURL = SavePhoto(url),
            MemberEmail = name,
            MemberPhoto = photo
        };
        db.ForumMessages.Add(m);
        db.SaveChanges();

        Clients.Caller.ReceiveImage(name, url, photo, "sender");
        Clients.Others.ReceiveImage(name, url, photo, "caller");
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your code as a text instead of images when asking a question, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for more details

Comment: I think you'd want to search up for *How to upload files with SignalR*